# Find a parametrization of $SL(2)$

Tags: differential-geometry

> If $SL(2)=\{A\in \mathcal{M}_2: \det(A)=1\}$, find a parametrization around the identity matrix $I_2$ and find the first fundamental form.

I've proved that $SL(2)$ is an hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^4$, so it has dimension $3$. However, I don't understand very well what does "around the identity" means. I think that if I have the parametrization I'll be able to compute the first fundamental form.

Thank you.

Comment: The identity matrix is an element of $SL(2)$. 'Around the identity' means you are supposed to find a parametrization for a neighbourhood of this matrix.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group is the set of matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ such that $ad-bc=1$. If you fix $a$, $b$ and $c$, then you can solve for $d$ using a somewhat obvious formula, and that formula works in a neighborhood of the point $(a,b,c)=(1,0,0)$ which gives the identity. This gives you a parametrization of the many points on the group including the identity.  I'll let you write it down explicitly and seeing if it gives a chart or not.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathrm{SL}_2$ is a quadric hypersurface, one way to get a parametrization near the point $I_2$ is to [stereographically project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Generalizations) $\mathrm{SL}_2$ onto the tangent hyperplane at $I_2$ from some other point (for instance, $-I_2$).